# Calculate returns in time series data R

Tags: r, database, time-series, xts, finance

R does not recognize my datatable as a panel, I have closing prices and totalreturn prices for a few decades, however sometimes months in between are missing, so a simple return calculation with lagged values does not work for two reasons: you don't want returns over lagged values that are not 1 month apart and it now takes returns over every company instead of having one time series per observation.  My solution is this:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(totret <- ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,totalreturn/lag(totalreturn)-1))

names(df1) <- c("date","company","totalreturn","close", "seriesid", "ticker","totret") 

df1 <- df1 %>%
group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(closeret <- ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,close/lag(close)-1))

names(df1) <- c("date","company","totalreturn","close", "seriesid", "ticker","totret", "closeret")
```

It is not fancy, but R does not allow a fancier solution because it will not recognize the new columns.
My data looks like:

```
date company returnprice close seriesid 
1 1888-01-31 x 2.500 2.500 0005 
2 1888-02-04 x 2.750 2.750 0005
3 1888-04-20 x 3.350 3.350 0005 
4 1895-01-30 y 7.500 4.350 0001
5 1895-02-26 y 7.800 4.650 0001
```

I am now able to get my data like:

```
date company totalreturn close seriesid totret closeret 
1 1888-01-31 x 2.500 2.500 0005 NA NA
2 1888-02-04 x 2.750 2.750 0005 0.1 0.1
3 1888-04-20 x 3.350 3.350 0005 NA NA
4 1895-01-30 y 7.500 4.350 0001 NA NA
5 1895-02-26 y 7.800 4.650 0001 0.04 0.06897
```

Comment: What is the following supposed to do: `df$totret <- df$close/lag(df$close))-1`?

Comment: It is supposed to calculate returns from closing prices. In finance people use (new/old) - 1 to get your % change from the old price.

Comment: Why not do this operation in `mutate`?

Comment: I tried: <br>
<code>xsub1 <- xsub %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(totret <- ((close)/lag(close))-1)</code> this does give those returns, however it does not allow for the missing months

Comment: After looking at your question, I would suggest first reading up on the basics of `dplyr`. I or someone else might give an answer but I think it will not be very useful in the long run. With `mutate` you say `mutate(New_Col=your calculation here)`

Comment: That did work Nelson, however the problem is that it does not allow for row 3 to be NA in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- df %>%
      group_by(seriesid) %>%
      mutate(totret <- ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,totalreturn/lag(totalreturn)-1))

names(df1) <- c("date","company","totalreturn","close", "seriesid", "ticker","totret") 

df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(seriesid) %>%
    mutate(closeret <- ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,close/lag(close)-1))

names(df1) <- c("date","company","totalreturn","close", "seriesid", "ticker","totret", "closeret")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example I added more dates just to see what happen when more than 3 rows should be NA, and your code works correctly. But, you will find and issue when a new year starts, since "December" > "January".

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate(totret = ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,totalreturn/lag(totalreturn)-1),
                               closeret = ifelse(month(date)-month(lag(date))>1,NA,close/lag(close)-1))



        date totalreturn close    totret   closeret
1 1888-01-28         2.5   2.5        NA         NA
2 1888-02-28         2.7   2.7 0.0800000 0.08000000
3 1888-03-28         3.0   3.3 0.1111111 0.22222222
4 1888-05-28         3.5   3.5        NA         NA
5 1888-08-28         2.8   4.0        NA         NA
6 1888-10-28         3.0   4.3        NA         NA
7 1888-12-28         3.2   4.5        NA         NA
8 1889-03-28         3.6   4.6 0.1250000 0.02222222
```

I'd suggest using `difftime()` and imputing NA when difference is higher than 31 days.

```
data3 <- data %>% mutate(totret = ifelse(difftime(date, lag(date), units = 'days')>31, NA, totalreturn/lag(totalreturn)-1),
                               closeret = ifelse(difftime(date, lag(date), units = 'days')>31, NA, close/lag(close)-1))

 date totalreturn close    totret  closeret
1 1888-01-28         2.5   2.5        NA        NA
2 1888-02-28         2.7   2.7 0.0800000 0.0800000
3 1888-03-28         3.0   3.3 0.1111111 0.2222222
4 1888-05-28         3.5   3.5        NA        NA
5 1888-08-28         2.8   4.0        NA        NA
6 1888-10-28         3.0   4.3        NA        NA
7 1888-12-28         3.2   4.5        NA        NA
8 1889-03-28         3.6   4.6        NA        NA
```

I tried also `difftime(dates[2], dates[1], units = 'secs') > duration(1, units = 'month')`, but it will not work for 31 days difference since a "month is 30.41667 days"

Comment: Using days will not solve the problem, because some at some months the date ends at 28th and other months at 30th. Maybe i should just create a variable that equal 12*year(date) and 1*month

Comment: That's true, but you are looking for difference higher than 31, so difference of 28 or 30 days will not fall into the wrong category.